# @Configuration bean not being loaded first

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a `@Configuration` bean which defines various beans in Java

```
@Configuration
public class jmsConfiguration {
   // Various @Bean definitions
}
```

I also have the folowing bean:

```
@Component
@Profile({"BATCH_MODE"})
public class BatchLauncher  {

    @Autowired
    private Launcher launcher;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
       launcher.launch();
       // The launcher bean encapsulates the logic to
       // get the Spring Batch JobLauncher bean,
       // build the job parameters and start the job
    }
}
```

The problem is this:
The `init()` method which gets our `Launcher` bean and starts the batch job is called *before* the `@Configuration` class has been initialized.
If the code `launcher.launch()` is commented out and the application run in debug, the debugger will stop in the code which constructs the various `@Bean`'s. However, when the `launcher.launch()` is there and is run, that code will get run first, which means that the beans on which the `ItemWriter` is dependent have not been properly initialized.

This is the code used to start the Spring context:

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
ctx.load("app-context.xml");
ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
ctx.refresh();
ctx.start();
```

This is how the Launcher bean is defined in XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.app" />
<beans>
       <bean id="launcher" class="com.company.Launcher" />
...
</beans>
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you simply letting Spring do its job? Just specify the `launch` method as the `init` method to the `Launcher` bean. No need to have the `BatchLauncher` class. Also you shouldn't be doing a lookup  but simply inject the `Launcher` into this code if you need it, that also solves your ordering problem. But as stated I would strongly suggest using the `init` method approach.

Comment: Have updated the question to use Autowired. Still the same issue - the PostConstruct on the BatchLauncher bean is called before the Configuration bean is initialized. So the ordering problem remains. (The first idea - use init method - not so simple here as there are other entry points into the BatchLauncher bean).

Comment: Is the launcher bean defined in the class "jmsConfiguration" or somewhere else?

Comment: it is defined in one of the Spring context files

Comment: We need your Spring configuration.

Comment: What is it you exactly want to achieve. There are no guarantees that in the init methods everything is already fully initialized, this is specially the case when proxies come into play. If you want to execute code after everything is properly initialized use an `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and use that for kicking of things.

Comment: Thanks - that's possibly the issue. The bean in question which is not being initialized is a CachingConnectionFactory for connecting to Solace

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DependsOn annotation on the BatchLauncher class to define the beans on which the class depends, if they are not put as constructor arguments or autowired fields.